# Setting user access permissions for QGIS and SpatiaLite database

Tags: qgis, spatialite, security

SpatiaLite databases seems to match all my desires to store GIS layers and table but an important question is:

If it is possible to limit writing to only one user, then what is the way to do it?

I read the cookbook and searched the internet without finding an answer.

I know that PostGIS is better for multi-access purposes but there are only three cartographers in my company and they don't have enough needs in GIS to switch to PostGIS, which is much more complicated than SpatiaLite.

Answer (score 4):

You can't really do this at the SQLite / SpatiaLite / QGIS level. You can do it at the filesystem level (e.g. by setting permissions or access control lists on the file) by only allowing one user (typically the file owner) to write to it, and everyone else only read access.

How to do that isn't really a GIS question, but for completeness:

- On Linux or similar unix systems, use chmod (man chmod for specific syntax).
- On Windows 7 or similar, right click on the database, select properties, and then the Security tab. Configure as required (see "Learn about access control and permissions" link at the bottom of the Security tab if you need more help).